# getting not found: NGINX Ingress

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, microservices, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to learn .NET Microservice. I have been following a great tutorial on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgVjEo3OGBI&t=16674s) (Time: 4:44:55, Adding An API Gateway). Everything worked well until NGINX Ingress came into the picture. I pasted the same YAML file from the GitHub account of the trainer I doubled checked all the things but couldn't find anything:

I can see all the pods and services are working fine:

[image]

[image]

I updated my host file.

[image]

What did I miss?

URL, I am using: http://acme.com/api/platforms/

Error: HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

The output of the Ingress YAML:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"networking.k8s.io/v1","kind":"Ingress","metadata":{"annotations":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"nginx","nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex":"true"},"name":"ingress-srv","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"rules":[{"host":"acme.com","http":{"paths":[{"backend":{"service":{"name":"platforms-clusterip-srv","port":{"number":80}}},"path":"/api/platforms","pathType":"Prefix"},{"backend":{"service":{"name":"commands-clusterip-srv","port":{"number":80}}},"path":"/api/c/platforms","pathType":"Prefix"}]}}]}}
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-18T00:12:41Z"
  generation: 1
  name: ingress-srv
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2274742"
  uid: a7376202-8b1b-4f1a-a42f-08de5f602192
spec:
  rules:
  - host: acme.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: platforms-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/platforms
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: commands-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/c/platforms
        pathType: Prefix
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: localhost
```

Services:
[image]

UPDATE: Tried below commands and got some new information:

[image]

UPDATE: Result of

> Kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx

[image]

Comment: Can you do a `k get ingress your-ingress-here -oyaml`?

Comment: No, there is no update. Still, trying to figure out the issue. @WytrzymałyWiktor

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper could you post the output from the first comment?

Comment: @AndD I updated the output. Sorry for the delay

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko I updated the output. Sorry for the delay

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I updated the output. Sorry for the delay

Comment: The error of the default back end can be ignored in your case, that is basically what the Nginx ingress would route requests to, if you ask for a path it doesn't know. But it looks like you can not reach the Nginx Ingress Pod itself. I would check the Pod logs, describe the Services and such to see if they are attached to their Pods correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the regex annotation from th ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: ingress-srv
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: acme.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: platforms-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/platforms
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: commands-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /api/c/platforms
        pathType: Prefix
```

or just try this `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: acme.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: commands-clusterip-srv
            port:
              number: 80
```

in above ingress, all requests will go to service `commands-clusterip-srv` so from browser side you pass anything either /api or /api/c ingress will route the traffic to that service if your host is `acme.com`

Error **404** clearly means there is some issue with your Nginx configuration **path** is not matching or **host** issue, Nginx not able to find upstream or target so it throws 404.

**Update**

Try adding IP and entry into the host file for

```
192.168.1.28 acme.com
```

i am not sure you have used the IP POD to curl ideally you should me using the `acme.com` as you can to access the data.

also hope you service, deployment and ingress are in same namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried both ways but got the same error. I updated the YAML file and ran the apply command.

Comment: Also, I am using postman on my local machine. URL: http://acme.com/api/platforms. Also, this sample 'acme.com' host is mentioned in the demo so I just used the same. I updated this host in the host file.

Comment: are you still getting the 404 or any other error cod ?

Comment: Yes, I am still getting same 404: <p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>. Also, I updated some new information in my question

Comment: updated answer please check. make sure your deployment service and ingress all are running into the same namespace. also dont use POD ip to CURL it will never work as those are internal IP managed by K8s. Use 192.168.1.28 your host machine IP or localhost.

Comment: Pod, deployments, service and ingress are in the Default namespace. I updated the hostname IP as well but still getting 404

Comment: check the logs of nginx ingress pods

Comment: I hope you are saying from this command : "kubectl logs ingress-nginx-controller-5c8d66c76d-rdnxb -n ingress-nginx" . No Error found there in the logs

Comment: That’s weird are you still saying that http backed issue ?

Comment: You mean this error which I mentioned while describe the ingress : "Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)". If yes, I am still getting it.

Comment: That’s weird, try checking the version of api for ingress and logs. Hope your pods and service are running properly.

Comment: yeah, is there any prior configuration for Ingress? As I follow a basic following example and also getting same 404 error. Example URL:https://matthewpalmer.net/kubernetes-app-developer/articles/kubernetes-ingress-guide-nginx-example.html

Comment: I updated my question, result of a "kubectl get pods --namespace=ingress-nginx". Not sure, all those 3 services should be in running state or not

Comment: Looking good there no error logs that’s weird when you are hitting Ingres

Comment: Any last suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Thank you Harsh for your precious time. I tried all the things but no error was found.

It was really a miracle that I am able to resolve it issue on HTTPS. I am able to access "https://acme.com/api/platforms". But still, HTTP is giving me the same error. However, I am fine with HTTPS